# DB not updating after putting the prepared statment in the code

Tags: php, mysql

So I have decided to put the prepared statement in my code and when I fill the information with all the valid details, a message pops up saying registration successful but no data actually goes in the Database

Here is the function code that I have;

```
        //check if form is submitted
        if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];



            //name can contain only alpha characters and space
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
                $error = true;
                $name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
            }
            if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $error = true;
                $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
            }
            if(strlen($password) < 6) {
                $error = true;
                $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
            }
            if($password != $cpassword) {
                $error = true;




          $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
            }
            if (!$error) 
            {
                // prepare and bind
                $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name,email,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
                $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $password);
                if($stmt->execute = true) {

                    $successmsg = "Successfully Registered! <a href='login.php'>Click here to Login</a>";

                } else {
                    $errormsg = "Error in registering...Please try again later!";
                }

            }
        }


        ?>
```

The Db structure in my php my admin;

```
        id(int 8)
        name(varchar 30)
        email(varchar 60)
        password(varchar 40)
```

I would appreciate a help, and thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need to call `$stmt->execute()`.  You aren't actually doing that right now if you check.

Comment: `if($stmt->execute = true)` that should read as `if($stmt->execute == true)` and I can already tell that you're not storing passwords safely. Yet, you're not checking for errors at all.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the help man

Comment: Its now saving to the DB. But ive noticed something very strage. The new things that are being added to the php my admin are being added to the top of the list rather than going to the very bottom. Any idea why?